# Having issues connecting to PostgreSQL Database in Django

Tags: python, django, web

I am getting the error

django.db.utils.OperationError: FATAL:database "/path/to/current/project/projectname/databasename" does not exist.

I have accessed the database both manually through psql, as well as through pgadmin4, and have verified in both instances that the database does exist, and I have verified that the port is correct.

Im not sure why I cant access the database, or why it would say the database cannot be found.

According to pgAdmin4, the database is healthy, and it is receiving at least 1 I/O per second, so it can be read and written to by...something?

I have installed both the psycopg2 and the psycopg2-binary just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer, or at least I do believe I did. It was a two part problem.

Part of it was I left os.path.join(base_dir...) included as part of the '' name section.

The other was I used an "@" character as part of my password. Once I changed the password, and I removed the os.path.join(base_dir...) portion, it worked.